# AngularJS: templateUrl works for a HTML template file, but it doesn't with a .JSP

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, jsp

Im building a controller-template in angularJS as simple as:

```
var maintest = angular.module("mainTest", []);
angular.module("mainTest")
        .component('mainscreen', {
        templateUrl: './services/fakeService.html',
        controller: function example(){
                    this.userData = 'Jospeh';
                }
        } );
```

If the template is a HTML file as shown above, it works fine. But if you try to use a .JSP template, it doesn't at all (code of fakeService.jsp below).

**HTML (fakeService.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div>
    Data to show: {{$ctrl.userData}}
</div>
```

Output of HTML (called from component mainscreen):

> Data to show: Jospeh

**JSP (fakeService.jsp):**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% 
out.print("Test if JSP code is processed.");
%>
<div>
    Data to show: {{$ctrl.userData}}
</div>
```

Output of JSP (called from component mainscreen):

> Test if JSP code is processed. Data to show: {{$ctrl.userData}}

Can I use AngularJS + JSP? If I can, how it comes this simple example doesn't work?

Thank you all.

Comment: JSP are translated into servlets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you are implementing the server side. I recommend to follow MVC deign approach and make the templates extension agnostic. Here is a sample from my project,

```
 // route for the home page
 .when('/home', {
     templateUrl : 'home',
     controller  : 'homeController'
 })
```

On the server side, I have an MVC controller, which captures the uri "/home", resolves the view  (it is up to the logic in the view resolver, whether it is going to be a jsp, or html or whatever) and passes the results back. This case, angular has no clue what is on the server side, which also promotes loose coupling.

Comment: Thank you, Imran.